# Socket.io - Getting client's IP always results in undefined

Tags: node.js, sockets

For my simple socket.io chat, I'm trying to prevent multi-clienting. So I figured, why not just get the client's IP and not allow it multiple times. However, I have been searching for hours on how to do this. I have found multiple solutions people have come up with and none seem to work for me. I have tried things like...

`socket.client.request.headers['x-forwarded-for']`

`socket.handshake.address.address`

`socket.handshake.headers('x-forwarded-for')`

`socket.handshake.headers['x-real-ip']`

and so on, yet they *all* return `undefined`. Perhaps it's the version of socket.io? This is what is required in package.json

`"express": "^4.10.2",
"socket.io": "^1.3.5"`

The following however, shows `::1`

`socket.request.connection.remoteAddress`

Perhaps *something* is wrong with my code - https://github.com/Crypting/chat

Everything else works fine - sending, receiving, etc.

Comment: What is your server environment.  Is the client connecting direct to the server or is the client connecting to a server proxy that then connected to your server?

Comment: `socket.request.connection.remoteAddress` is the supported way to get the remote IP address if there is no proxy in your server setup.  FYI, a cookie to identify each browser might also work.

Comment: There shouldn't be a proxy on localhost. No matter what browser I use, it always comes up undefined. I've also tested it on a vps behind a no-ip service (which would be a proxy) and the result stays the same.

Comment: Your question says you got `::1` which is IPv6 vernacular for `localHost`.  That would be correct if you were connecting from the same server.

Comment: Oh... okay that works even with the no-ip service, showing the correct IP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment worked for you, I'll put it in an answer.

`socket.request.connection.remoteAddress` is the supported way to get the remote IP address.

If you are connecting to localHost, it may show `::1` which is the IPv6 shortcut for 127.0.0.1.